# How to get return value of generator after closing the generator?

Tags: python-3.x

I want to get return value after closing generator. And it isn't allowed?

```
def generator_alpha():
    try:
        yield "z"
    except GeneratorExit:
        pass
    return "t"

if __name__ == "__main___":
    myAlphas = generator_alpha()
    next(myAlphas)
    myAlphas.close()
    #now what should i do let me get 't'?
```

Comment: So sorry! I first asked question and my english is poor. I don't know how to make code pretty. And where's my code indent?

Comment: When you [edit] the question you select the text that should be in a code block and either use Ctrl-K or click the `{}` button in the editor and it'll put it in a code block.

Comment: From the docs: "Catching the `GeneratorExit` exception and returning a value is illegal and will trigger a `RuntimeError`".  What you're trying to do is explicitly disallowed, although I have no idea of the reasoning behind that - seems like it could have easily been made the return value of `.close()`.  (I guess one objection to that is that you couldn't distinguish between actually returning `None`, and the usual case of exiting due to the `GeneratorExit`.)

Comment: and why are You catching generator exception inside this generator ?

Comment: @JonClements Thanks a lot. I get it : )

Comment: @jasonharper Thank you! Becasue I have just now known that 'yield' should be absent behind catching `GeneratorExit` but some logic codes could exist. And I think of that only getting the returning value makes code meaningful. In fact, I tried some methods but failed, I used google searching but no result. Thank you and your answer again.

Comment: @Take_Care_ Because I get a infomation that 'yield' can't appear behind catching `GeneratorExit` and other logic codes such as `print` can appear from internet. And if  there is `return`, how to get it's value , I wonder.